# Cypress: Run all specs but create a loop without run specs

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I have a problem with Cypress.io, here is my problem :

I have 4 different test files here :

**integration/socle_full_ts_dev/1_register_user.spec.js**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import { first, last } from 'random-name';

describe('Validate register in Socle-Full-JS DEV', () => {
    xit('Register ramdom user on Socle', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'auth/register');
        setTypeInRegisterForm(false)
        cy.wait(1000);
        cy.get('.register-form-button').click();
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    xit('Register ramdom user on Socle with button enter', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'auth/register');
        setTypeInRegisterForm(true);
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    xit('Validated register first user', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('MAIL_URL'));
        setTypeInEtherealForm();
        cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2) > a').click();
        clickLinkInEmail();
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    xit('Validated register second user', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('MAIL_URL'));
        setTypeInEtherealForm();
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2) > a').click();
        clickLinkInEmail();
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });
});

const setTypeInRegisterForm = (isEnter) => {
    const firstName = first();
    const lastName = last();
    const email = firstName + '.' + lastName + '@example.fr';
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/register_user.json', {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email
    });
    cy.get('#FIRST_NAME').type(firstName);
    cy.get('#LAST_NAME').type(lastName);
    cy.get('#EMAIL').type(email);
    cy.get('#PASSWORD').type('toto');
    cy.get('#PASSWORD_CONFIRM').type('toto');
    if (isEnter) {
        cy.get('#ORGANIZATION_NAME').type('Needone{enter}');
    } else {
        cy.get('#ORGANIZATION_NAME').type('Needone');
    }
}

const setTypeInEtherealForm = () => {
    cy.get('#address').type('toto.toto@ethereal.email');
    cy.get('#password').type('LALALLA{enter}');
    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .nav-link').click();
}

const clickLinkInEmail = () => {
    cy.get('iframe').then((iframe) => {
        const body = iframe.contents().find('body');
        cy.wrap(body).find('a').click();
    });
}
```

**integration/socle_full_ts_local/1_register_user_local.spec.js**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import { first, last } from 'random-name';

describe('Validate register in Socle-Full-JS LOCAL', () => {
    it('Register ramdom user on Socle', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'auth/register');
        setTypeInRegisterForm(false)
        cy.wait(1000);
        cy.get('.register-form-button').click();
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    it('Register ramdom user on Socle with button enter', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'auth/register');
        setTypeInRegisterForm(true);
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    it('Validated register first user', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('MAIL_URL'));
        setTypeInEtherealForm();
        cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2) > a').click();
        clickLinkInEmail();
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    it('Validated register second user', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('MAIL_URL'));
        setTypeInEtherealForm();
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2) > a').click();
        clickLinkInEmail();
        cy.wait(3000);
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });
});

const setTypeInRegisterForm = (isEnter) => {
    const firstName = first();
    const lastName = last();
    const email = firstName + '.' + lastName + '@example.fr';
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/register_user.json', {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password: 'password'
    });
    cy.get('#FIRST_NAME').type(firstName);
    cy.get('#LAST_NAME').type(lastName);
    cy.get('#EMAIL').type(email);
    cy.get('#PASSWORD').type('password');
    cy.get('#PASSWORD_CONFIRM').type('password');
    if (isEnter) {
        cy.get('#ORGANIZATION_NAME').type('Needone{enter}');
    } else {
        cy.get('#ORGANIZATION_NAME').type('Needone');
    }
}

const setTypeInEtherealForm = () => {
    cy.get('#address').type('toto.toto@ethereal.email');
    cy.get('#password').type('LALALAALAL{enter}');
    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .nav-link').click();
}

const clickLinkInEmail = () => {
    cy.get('iframe').then((iframe) => {
        const body = iframe.contents().find('body');
        cy.wrap(body).find('a').click();
    });
}
```

**integration/socle_full_ts_local/2_login_user_local.spec.js**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import * as userRegister from "../../fixtures/register_user.json";

describe('Test login on Socle-Full-JS LOCAL', () => {
    it('Login user on Socle', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'auth/login');
        cy.get('#USERNAME').type(userRegister.email);
        cy.get('#PASSWORD').type(userRegister.password);
        cy.get('.login-form-button').click();
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    it('Login user on Socle with button enter', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'auth/login');
        cy.get('#USERNAME').type(userRegister.email);
        cy.get('#PASSWORD').type(userRegister.password + '{enter}');
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('LOCAL_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });
});
```

**integration/socle_full_ts_dev/2_login_user.spec.js**

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import * as userRegister from "../../fixtures/register_user.json";

describe('Test login on Socle-Full-JS DEV', () => {
    xit('Login user on Socle', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'auth/login');
        cy.get('#USERNAME').type(userRegister.email);
        cy.get('#PASSWORD').type(userRegister.password);
        cy.get('.login-form-button').click();
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });

    xit('Login user on Socle with button enter', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'auth/login');
        cy.get('#USERNAME').type(userRegister.email);
        cy.get('#PASSWORD').type(userRegister.password + '{enter}');
        cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.env('HERUKU_URL') + 'showcase/app/home');
    });
});
```

And the problem that I meet is that when I want to launch all the tests at the same time it turns in a loop and does not get out of it.
I checked the web to see if someone had already had the problem and I didn't find ...
here is a video demonstrating the problem :

[image: Cypress problem gif]

Here is what i tried :

- To put tests standby with `xit`
- Look in the documentation if there was anything to do with memory allocation...
- Separate tests with folders

My tests are not that complicated I just test the registration of a user and the login of the same user...

If someone has an idea ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i have a solutions of this problem :

In my tests I have :

`it('Register ramdom user on Socle', () => {
    // test
});`

and to solve the problem just convert its into :

`it('Validated register first user', function () {
   // test
});`

I don't know why, but it work !

> If anyone knows why i am taker :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `function ()` will allow to transfer context between the code blocks, whereas the fat arrow function does not allow context transfer (this comes from JS logic, nothing to do with Cypress)